# Sind Passivkonstruktionen in denen das Subjekt nicht vollständig realisiert wurde grammatikalisch richtig?

Tags: grammaticality, passive, definite-article, subject

In einem Interview habe ich sehr häufig Aussagen erhalten, in denen das Subjekt nicht vollständig realisiert wurde. Gezeigt wurden transitive Ereignisse, auf die die Probanden mit Passivkonstruktionen antworten sollten. Statt "Der Kater wird gebissen" wurde sehr häufig "Der wird gebissen" versprachlicht. Sind derartige Aussagen als richtig zu bewerten?

Comment: Oder wenn das Subjekt gar nicht existiert: "Kannst du das Auto noch tanken?" "Wird gemacht!"

Comment: Hat das speziell mit dem Passiv zu tun? Die Frage könntest du doch auch einfach für »der beißt« stellen.

Answer (score 8):

Der Satz ist korrekt. "Der" ist in diesem Fall ein Demonstrativpronomen und damit ein vollständiges Subjekt.